# Java library for converting XML to syntax colored HTML

Tags: java, xml, syntax-highlighting

I have a Java string of XML content. I use Velocity to generate some HTML reports, and this XML needs to be included into one of those HTML files. It would be nice if this XML is syntax colored and formatted. Does anyone know of a Java library to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/

Comment: This link doesn't work.  However, the library exists in the central Maven repository: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.uwyn%7Cjhighlight%7C1.0%7Cjar

Comment: This is way old now, but I was looking for the same thing and found jhighlight as Github:  https://github.com/codelibs/jhighlight

Answer (score 2):

Using [XSLT and CSS by Oliver Becker](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/):

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
InputStream xslt = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xmlverbatim.xsl"); // or FileInputStream
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
t.setParameter("indent-elements", "yes");
ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
t.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml)), new StreamResult(s));
byte[] out = s.toByteArray();
```

Comment: The website this answer links to is gone, and without it, the remaining code is of little use...

Answer (score 0):

How about transforming your xml to html using a XSLT stylesheet and the transform API.
See **Transform XML into HTML using XSLT**: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0407.html

Comment: The idea is that the output looks like XML, but with syntax colouring.

Comment: XSLT can do that by replacing, say, <span class="codeKeyWord">..</span> with something like <span class="codeKeyWord" style="color:green">..</span>. It's just not very clean way to do it.